# Calling a GetAll method from a Web Api from your C# client

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api2

I was looking at examples online and found a tutorial on retrieving products that uses a C# WEB API service and a C# console application as the client however, the tutorial defines a function in the service to get all products however, it does not tell you how to call it from the client:

```
public IEnumerable<Product> GetAllProducts()
{
    ...
}
```

The other CRUD methods declare using IHttpActionResult so I was confused how to call it.

So in my client I blindly attempted to call doing the following which is obviously incorrect:

```
using (var client = new HttpClient())
{
    client.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://localhost:59888/");
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

    // HTTP GET ALL
    HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync("api/products");
    if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
    {
        List<Model.Product> products = await.response.Content.ReadAsAsync<IEnumerable<Model.Product>();
    }
}
```

This gives me a syntax error. So how do I code it them? Do I need to change the server or the client code or both?

For a single product the code is and this works:

```
// HTTP GET Specific Product
response = await client.GetAsync("api/products/1");
if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
{
    Model.Product product = await response.Content.ReadAsAsync<Model.Product>();        
}
```

and the server is:

```
public IHttpActionResult GetProduct(int id)
{
    var product = repository.GetByID(id);
    if (product != null)
        return Ok(product);
    else
        return NotFound();     
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
List<Model.Product> products = await.response.Content.ReadAsAsync<IEnumerable<Model.Product>();
```

You missed a closing `>` at the end. Correct:

```
var products = await.response.Content.ReadAsAsync<IEnumerable<Model.Product>>();
```

Comment: Gee thanks I so dumb can I delete this post now, obviously cannot implicity cast to a generic list from an IEnumerable list however, I will figure that one out

Comment: But you can append `.ToList()` at the end of an `IEnumerable` to get it as a list. I even changed it to `var`, so the left should be of type`IEnumerable<Model.Product>>` which should cause an error in that line.